# if the click is not on a specific div do the following

Tags: jquery

How do you create a jQuery if statement that checks if a div is clicked, and if so do one thing.  If not, do another action?

Current jQuery

```
$("#button_a").click(function() { $("#div_a").hide(); });

else if #button_a was not clicked, then do something else
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can take advantage of event bubbling by registering your `click` event handler on the document and using [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to determine the element that initiated the event. Something like:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.id === "button_a") {
        $("#div_a").hide();
    } else {
        // Do something else...
    }
});
```

Comment: You must pass the event.. $(document).click(function(event) {

Comment: @Thilo, true, too early in the morning I guess... Answer updated, thanks for the heads-up :)